# Seeking source of curated/cleansed data for 2016 Canadian Census?

Tags: data-request, data-format, census, data-portal, canada

I am working with open data sources and the 2016 Canadian Census is of great interest to me. The Canadian Statistics website provides **boundary files**, which work great, and some **aggregated census data**, which doesn't work so great.

The problem I'm having with the **aggregated census data** is that the data is too 'long' and 'narrow' e.g.

[image: 'long' and 'narrow' data]

whereas my work requires the data to be 'shorter' and 'wider'
 e.g.

[image: 'shorter' and 'wider' data]

Does anyone know of a person or organisation that has solved this issue and made the data publicly available?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question so that you just ask about how to reformat your data. Your actual problem has nothing to do with the Canadian Census. Don't forget to add what format the data is in (csv?)

Comment: Thanks for the advise but I am aware of how to reformat the data myself. I know that there are other open data sources (e.g. the US census) for which the formatting and cleansing task has been done and made available so I was hoping the same might be done for this data source

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well and have opted not to use the aggregated data in some cases because of how badly it's formatted. If you have access through a Canadian university, I`d highly recommend speaking with your librarian about gaining access to UofT's the [CHASS Data Centre](http://datacentre.chass.utoronto.ca/). They maintain a database of cleaned/geoprocessed census data and make it VERY easy to perform table joins and subsequent analyses with the results.

Unfortunately, their network of universities that they offer data to is not open to all universities and, AFAIK, they don't provide data outside of the academic networks.